# VB Net ObservableCollection not updating ListView correctly

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

Just learning WPF so updating an old but useful program. I do programming as a hobby. Most of the learning I do is from the internet and I have searched for the answer to this for some days, so grateful for any help.

I'm using an Observablecollection to see how it works. My issue is that the list view that the Observablecollection is bound to doesn't show the correct data. I added a message box in to debug. After I did that, it worked perfectly, although I had to hit OK every time. After extensive reading, I was expecting the listview to update on every add (no Addrange method) but all it does is show the right number of entries but every row contains the last add.

I've changed the XAML so many times and the code behind but cannot seem to understand what I have done incorrectly or more importantly why it works with the MsgBox. The code below is the final incarnation of all the changes, not that pretty!

```
'convert from datatable to observable collection
    For x1 = 0 To DBdtPW.Rows.Count - 1
        PWResultHolder.PWNominalDia = DBdtPW.Rows(x1).Item(0)
        PWResultHolder.PWInternalDia = DBdtPW.Rows(x1).Item(1).ToString
        PWResultHolder.PWInternalArea = DBdtPW.Rows(x1).Item(2).ToString
        PWResultHolder.PWWithin = DBdtPW.Rows(x1).Item(3).ToString
        PWResultHolder.PWVelocity = DBdtPW.Rows(x1).Item(4).ToString
        PWResultHolder.PWPressureDropPM = DBdtPW.Rows(x1).Item(5).ToString
        PWResults.Add(PWResultHolder)
        'MsgBox(PWResultHolder.PWNominalDiaValue, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Input")
    Next
```

Again, thanks for any help.

```
Public Class ClsPWSizing

Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public PWPipeType As String 'Pipework material
Public PWPipeTypeList As New ObservableCollection(Of String) 'For populating pipe type combo box
Public PWFluidTemperatureList As New ObservableCollection(Of String) 'For populating temperature combo box
Public PWGlycolPerCentList As New ObservableCollection(Of String) 'For populating glycol combo box
Public PWResults As New ObservableCollection(Of clsPWFluidResult) 'For populating result listview
Public PWMinVelvalue As String 'Pipework minimum velocity
Public PWMaxVelvalue As String 'Pipework maximum velocity
Public PWMinPDvalue As String 'Pipework minimum pressure drop
Public PWMaxPDvalue As String 'Pipework maximum pressure drop
Public PWFluidTemperature As String ' Fluid temperature in the pipe
Public PWGlycolPerCent As String 'Percentage of glycol in fluid
Public PWDensity As String 'Density of fluid
Public PWDynVisc As String 'Dynamic viscosity of fluid
Public PWMassFlowRateValue As String 'Mass flow rate of fluid
Public GrdPWSizingVisible As System.Windows.Visibility 'Is the grid visible?

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

    Public Property PWResultListView()
    Get
        Return PWResults
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value)
        PWResults = value
    End Set
End Property
```

XAML:

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstVwPWResults" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="405" Margin="612,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="637" ItemsSource="{Binding PWResultListView, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Nom Dia" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWNominalDia}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Int Dia" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWInternalDia}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Area" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWInternalArea}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Within" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWWithin}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Velocity" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWVelocity}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Pressure Drop" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWPressureDropPM}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Maybe there is an error in setting the ObservableCollection to ItemsSource of the ListView. Post your vb code and xaml.

Comment: emoacht, not sure what you need but the xaml is; <ListView x:Name="lstVwPWResults" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="405" Margin="612,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="637" ItemsSource="{Binding PWResultListView, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> I would say that I have changed this on a number of times using binding path etc but I'm completely stumped. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: The name of ObservableCollection does not match... Edit this question and add minimal reproducible code. It means the minumum code which other people can try and see your problem. Copy your project and remove all unrelated things. The data shall be replaced with fake. Length does not matter.

Comment: emoacht, hope the above helps. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code still misses necessary parts to reproduce the problem but okay, I can guess. I removed all non-essential parts and add fake method to populate the ObservableCollection.

Item class for ObservableCollection

```
Public Class clsPWFluidResult
    Public Property PWNominalDia As String
    Public Property PWInternalDia As String
    Public Property PWInternalArea As String
    Public Property PWWithin As String
    Public Property PWVelocity As String
    Public Property PWPressureDropPM As String
End Class
```

ViewModel class which owns the ObservableCollection.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class clsPWSizing
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public PWResults As New ObservableCollection(Of clsPWFluidResult) 'For populating result listview

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Property PWResultListView()
        Get
            Return PWResults
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            PWResults = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Pupulate()
        For Each indexString In Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(x) x.ToString())
            Dim PWResultHolder As New clsPWFluidResult()

            PWResultHolder.PWNominalDia = "NominalDia" & indexString
            PWResultHolder.PWInternalDia = "InternalDia" & indexString
            PWResultHolder.PWInternalArea = "InternalArea" & indexString
            PWResultHolder.PWWithin = "Within" & indexString
            PWResultHolder.PWVelocity = "Velocity" & indexString
            PWResultHolder.PWPressureDropPM = "PressureDropPM" & indexString

            PWResults.Add(PWResultHolder)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code behind of View (MainWindow.xaml.vb)

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim vm = New clsPWSizing()
        Me.DataContext = vm
        vm.Pupulate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

XAML of View (MainWindow.xaml)

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PWResultListView}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100"
                            Header="Nom Dia" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWNominalDia}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Int Dia" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWInternalDia}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Area" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWInternalArea}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Within" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWWithin}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Velocity" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWVelocity}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" 
                            Header="Pressure Drop" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PWPressureDropPM}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This code works as expected. So there should be a problem somewhere you have not posted. Please check the difference between this code and your actual code to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: The problem was in the for loop. I only initialised the pwresultholder once but added in your line to create one each time. Thank you so much. I still don't knw why it works with the MsgBox in but I'll research that one a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ViewModel(MVVM), implement INotifyPropertyChanged

use this

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

In your Collection's(ItemsSource of ListView) Setter, do this

```
private ObservableCollection<someType> _pWResults;
public ObservableCollection<someType> PWResults
{
   get{ return _pWResults }
   set
   {
      _pWResults = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("PWResults");
   }
 }
```

Sorry for providing the eg code in c#

Comment: This is wrong way to notify the change of __items__ in an ObservableCollection because this will notify the change of ObservableCollection itself.

Comment: @emoacht this is the right way to do it. The *OnPropertyChanged* **method** will notify the WPF control about any changes done to the Collection

Comment: You mixed up property change notification of VM and that of ObservableCollection which is a member of VM. Your code implements INotifyPropertyChanged to VM but it has nothing to do with property change of ObservableCollection itself. ObservableCollection has built-in functionality of INotifyPropertyChanged (and INotifyCollectionChanged) and does not need such code.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I can read C# so no problem. The class includes INotifyProprtyChanged for other controls but I understood observablecollection included the ICollectionChanged and you didn't need to implement anything, just use the Add method. The most interesting thing is it works if I leave the message box in but doesn't when I comment that line out as shown in the code above. There are no errors on build or in debug. Again any help greatly appreciated as I know I'm doing something wrong.